# SSIS 2008 Tasks Executing Simultaneously

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, etl

I am not an expert, but I have some experience with BIDS/SSIS 2012. I recently had to start working in 2008 for reasons beyond my control, and I am running into a problem I never saw in 2012. My precedence constraints don't seem to work. I have a series of Script and Execute SQL tasks, and then once those are completed successfully, a sequence container should start running some Data Flow tasks. However, when I execute the package, the first task (Execute SQL) and the Sequence container both begin simultaneously. The preceding steps need to take place for the Data Flow tasks to succeed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or how to fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

Please see below for an image of the package:

[image]

"Prepare Tables" and "Get Adj Memo Sheet" begin at the same time.

Comment: Provide a screenshot for the package

Comment: @Hadi screenshot added

Answer (score 1):

Hope that i am not mis-understanding your question. It looks like you didn't connected the tasks correctly. Here some info on tasks execution.

There are 2 ways that a task begin executing

- at the beginning of package execution (if this task is not connected to a previous task)
- after a previous task finish executing (when tasks are connected)

If multiple task are not connected to previous tasks. They will begin ececuting in parallel when the package starts executing.

Also if they are grouped inside a sequence container they will start executing when in parallel when the sequence starts.

*Screenshots for parallel execution*

[image]

[image]

*Screenshots for sequentiel execution*

[image]

Comment: Good efforts Haidi!!

Comment: @Haidi That's great information, thank you! I don't think that's the issue though. I added a screenshot, and I think that I have everything linked correctly with precedence constraints.

Comment: @KE0GSD which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: @Hadi I'm using SSMS 2008 R2

Comment: Try recreating the package with same components. It can be a property that cause this issue